# Resize bootstrap grid column when it's empty

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

I’m using the latest bootstrap. I have three bootstrap `col-sm` grid columns. In every column there are bootstrap cards. When I delete all cards in a certain column I want to resize its width to 20px. I have tried to use CSS but the column did not resize. Is there a solution?

One more thing - when the column is resized will the other columns resize correspondingly to fill the empty space?

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          This is some text within a card body.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          This is some text within a card body.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          This is some text within a card body.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          This is some text within a card body.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      This column should resize when it's empty.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please add the relevant parts of your code as a code snippet using the `[<>]`-like button in the question editor?

Comment: Hello. I've added the relevant code.

Comment: You can make use of `.col-sm:empty { width: 20%; }` if it has no content which includes whitespace.

Comment: I am interested in the approach you took to solve this.  We don't always know when a chart, card or table will be empty.  Having a empty class can be toggled with a boolean value.  But would prefer something that takes more advantage of flex properties